# Is the inline package redundant yet for Rcpp?

Tags: rcpp

In his excellent introduction to Rcpp, [Eddelbuettel (2013)](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/book/978-1-4614-6867-7), Dirk writes, on page 32:

> But **inline** is very mature and tested, and the attributes functions
>   are at this point not of comparable maturity, the remainder of the
>   book will continue to use **inline** and its slightly more verbose
>   expression.

Now I must admit that I don't like using `inline` since having to include code as one string block is just too cumbersome, whatever the other advantages of `inline` might be. It is one of the few distracting factors in an otherwise excellent book (see the code in section 1.2.7 for an example).

And using attributes + `sourceCpp` has never lead to substantial problems for me. My questions are:

- Given the 2 years that have elapsed since the publication of the book, have attributes caught up with `inline`?
- Are there edge cases that `inline` can handle and attributes cannot?

Comment: That question has been discussed numerous times as well. Use Attributes.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The more I read the book, the clearer Rcpp use becomes -- thanks. One more question that I wanted to ask is, when, if ever, might Attributes support exporting C++ classes like Modules does (or indeed using Modules)? What are the inherent difficulties in doing this?

Comment: Attributes actually supports Modules. But for that, maybe ask a new question, and possibly ask it on the list.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Have posted to the `Rcpp-devel` mailing list. Thanks.